# Mapping Nested Array Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a value that is nested in an array. I am trying to access "total_state_changes" in this response:

```
{
  "sis_imports": [
    {
      "id": 5130,
      "created_at": "2023-08-21T18:02:22Z",
      "started_at": "2023-08-21T18:02:25Z",
      "ended_at": "2023-08-21T18:02:26Z",
      "updated_at": "2023-08-21T18:02:27Z",
      "progress": 100,
      "workflow_state": "imported_with_messages",
      "data": {
        "import_type": "instructure_csv",
        "downloadable_attachment_ids": [
          954469
        ],
        "supplied_batches": [
          "account"
        ],
        "counts": {
          "change_sis_ids": 0,
          "accounts": 1,
          "terms": 0,
          "abstract_courses": 0,
          "courses": 0,
          "sections": 0,
          "xlists": 0,
          "users": 0,
          "logins": 0,
          "enrollments": 0,
          "admins": 0,
          "group_categories": 0,
          "groups": 0,
          "group_memberships": 0,
          "grade_publishing_results": 0,
          "user_observers": 0,
          "error_count": 0,
          "warning_count": 3
        },
        "running_immediately": true,
        "completed_importers": [
          "account"
        ],
        "statistics": {
          "total_state_changes": 1,
```

Here is my mapping:

```
    var statechange = data.sis_imports["data"]["statistics"].map (({
        total_state_changes
    }) => [total_state_changes]);
```

I am getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statistics').

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `sis_imports` is an Array; it doesn’t have a key `"data"`. Access the members themselves & their properties.

Comment: `sis_imports` is an ARRAY

Comment: @esqew sorry I am lost. How should I access it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data object contains one key `sis_imports` which is an array with single element. To reach that only element you should go like this:

```
var statechange = data.sis_imports[0]["data"]["statistics"];
```

Regarding your mapping function it won't work well too since you can't call method `map` on objects. But you can call map over keys, values and other properties of objects. In your case, you seem to map your `statistics` object's `total_state_changes` property's value into an array. You can do this using this code:

```js
var statechange = data.sis_imports[0]["data"]["statistics"];
data.sis_imports[0]["data"]["statistics"] = [statechange.total_state_changes];
```

This way your `statistics` object wi have the structure of following:

```js
{
  "sis_imports": [
    {
      ...,
      "data": {
        ...,
        "statistics": [1]
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
```

I hope this helps!